# Using JSX to edit the scale of an inline css element

Tags: javascript, css, jsx, transform

I am attempting to animate an element increasing in size using JSX and inline CSS

```js
const iconHtml = `<div style="background: url('${iconUrl}'); width: 100%; height: 100%; transition: 0.5s; background-repeat: round; transform: scale(4);"onmouseover="this.style.scale=2;"onmouseout="this.style.scale=1;"" >
     <p style="margin-bottom: 0;position: relative;left: 70px;width: max-content;top: 20px;font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600;>
            ${steps?.length < 10 ? item.title : ""}
     </p>
  </div>`;
const icon = L.divIcon({
  html: !hovered ? iconHtml : iconHtml,
});
```

currently, I am trying to add a new if statement at the placeholder of  `HTML: !hovered ? iconHtml :iconHtml`, and have tried different ways such as iconHtml.style.scale however it continues to give me errors. Is there any way to use javascript to change the size of the item in an if statement outside of the inline CSS? if not is there a way to put an if statement into the inline that says if `!hovered` then it changes the size?

thank you in advance

Comment: That doesn't look like JSX?

Comment: The full program uses JSX but it isn't implemented in here, is there a way to do it that just uses javascript? or anything in JSX that I can take advantage of to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `transform: scale();` in combination with a css variable (also called "custom properties"), and then let React change that variable's value. [Example of transform: scale() with variable](https://codepen.io/danwilson/pen/oBrOGW).

Programmatically changing a css variable's value works like this: `elem.style.setProperty('--my-var-name', 'valueGoesHere');`.

However, your problem sounds like it should be solved purely with CSS. Changing a style on hover is a super common pure css task.

Comment: I have tried using elem.style.setProperty previously but I get an error and a statement that it failed to compile, and I do not know how to remedy it

Comment: @Alex Please provide the code you tried and the exact error message, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I attempted  html: !hoveredStep ? iconHtml : elem.style.setProperty('iconHtml', '6'), and I was given Failed to compile, 'elem' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @Alex elem is a reference to a DOM element, which you need to select first. I'd really recommend to look into the `:hover` css pseudo selector for your problem.